# Exibir mensagens de uma lista de forma sequencial

Tags: javascript

Criei esta função `random`, mas como estou aprender JS ainda... estou confuso.

Este código faz com que variáveis acima apareçam em modo *random*. Mas como faço para aparecerem normal 1 por 1 sem ser *random*...?

```
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "  apenas <span class='text-primary'><strong>15 moedas.</strong></span>",
    },          
    {
      text: "evolua connosco! <i class='fas fa-heart'></i>.",
    },  
    {
      text: " Procura alugar uma casa de f&eacute;rias? Visite eira Vacation</span>.</a>",
    },          
    {
      text: "  Compre j&aacute; em <a href=''><span class='text-primary'>Comprar Moedas</span>.</a>",
    }          

  ];
  function random() {
    var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ' + quote.text + '';
  }
  random(); // Executa a primeira vez.
  setInterval(random, 4000);
})();
```

---

Edição

```
  function random() {

    var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ' + quote.text + '';        
  }    

  random();
```

Comment: Você criou a função, então presumo que saiba o que o `Math.random()` faz, certo? Então o que você precisa é um contador controlado, que seja incrementado de um em um, mostrando as mensagens de forma sequencial.

Comment: Sim sei que essa função faz a contagem e mostra em random, mas demomento fiquei confuso pois apenas desejo que mostre sequencial.

Answer (score 2):

Basta criar um laço para percorrer o array de forma sequêncial:

```
for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) quote = quotes[i];
```

Não é necessário colocar as instruções repetidas entre chaves por se tratar de apenas uma instrução. Mas caso precise de mais, é feito assim:

```
for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
  //Funções aqui
}
```

Lembrete: Ao criar essa variável `i` no laço, ela só existe no laço!

Comment: humm desta forma? Ele continua a fazer random

**      function random() {
        var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
        for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) { 
            document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ' + quote.text + '';        
        }
      }**

Comment: continua random..

Comment: Não, fora da função random, antes mesmo dela ser executada.

Comment: acima eu meti a edição como disse, mas da erro igual "undefined" @mutlei

Comment: Ah, agora entendi. Dentro valor que vai ser atribuido ao innerHTML, você tá usando `quote.text`. Usa `quotes[i].text`.

Comment: simplesmente fica parado na ultima quote e nao avança para as restantes

Comment: sabe me dizer o que esta errado? @mutlei

Comment: Você quer que ele liste as citações, correto? Então é só mudar o `innerHTML = (string)` para `innerHTML += (string)`. Se quiser colocar cada uma em uma linha diferente, você pode colocar a string dentro de um `<p>` ou colocar um `<br>` no final da string

Comment: Epa... nada disso.. O que eu quero é.. que ele mostre cada 1 frase 1 por 1 em cada 4seg... Como o meu codigo acima mostrou, ele mostra 1 depois outra, depois outra. O problema do meu codigo é.. ele faz Random, ele simplesmente pode mostrar 1 farse 3x nos mesmos 4 seg.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79749/discussion-between-mutlei-and-user21312321).